# jquery.load() is a shorthand for what?

Tags: jquery, conventions

I've been looking over the jQuery docs and it indicates that [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is a [shorthand method](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/), but doesn't explain what that function is.

For example, `.get(url, [data], [callback(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)], [dataType])` is shorthand for:

```
 $.ajax({
   url: url,
   data: data,
   success: success,
   dataType: dataType
 });
```

And this is fully explained in the documentation, but .load() does something somewhat different and it simply seems to be an outlier of the convention of the `.get`, `.getJSON`, `.getScript`, and `.post` which are similar to the above example.

What exactly is .load shorthand for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

is shorthand for

```
if($('#result').length) {
  $.get('ajax/test.html', {}, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    if(textStatus=="success" || textStatus=="notmodified") {
      $('#result').html(data);
    }
    alert('Load was performed.');
  });
}
```

You can see what exactly .load() does by inspecting source code here: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js (It's around line 5585).

**Note:**
You can pass selector after your url (you have to separate it by space). If you do that not all of the response will be inserted in your document but rather only the part of target document selected by this selector.

Comment: Note: The event handling suite also has a method named .load(). Which one is fired depends on the set of arguments passed.

Comment: This doesn't seem to account for the selector.

Comment: Example shows load() applied for nodes selected by selector #result

Comment: Well, it puts data as from the ajax request to #result, but I mean line 5594 where `var off = url.indexOf(" ");` seperates the URL and selector argument and creates a div for selection of elements inside the request.

Answer (score 1):

`.load()` takes the `.get()` method and goes one step further by automatically populating a specified DOM collection with the content of a successful AJAX request.

Basically, instead of writing this:

```
$.get(url, function(data, ts, xhr) {
   $("#someElement").html(data);
});
```

You can just write this:

```
$("#someElement").load(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

> This method is the simplest way to
>   fetch data from the server. It is
>   roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data,
>   success) except that it is a method
>   rather than global function and it has
>   an implicit callback function. When a
>   successful response is detected (i.e.
>   when textStatus is "success" or
>   "notmodified"), .load() sets the HTML
>   contents of the matched element to the
>   returned data.

From the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: *"It is roughly equivalent to... except that..."* should answer the question. Why the downvote?